# Django App Engine deployment stops responding after 5 or 6 requests

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have been fighting this for a while now.

### Setup:

I have Django 4 application running on Google App Engine (Standard) connected to Cloud SQL.

### Issue:

I will load a page, and either refresh it 5 (ish) times or load 5 (ish) different pages.  Then the application just stops responding.

### Observations:

No errors are thrown.  I have looked at the metrics and it doesn't appear anything is off.  When I go to the instances page, they say they are "restarting" but they just are frozen there for many many minutes.

Things I have tried:

- Manual, Basic, and Automatic Scaling
- Warmup requests
- Larger instance sizes
- Higher scaling thresholds
- Non-zero min instance sizes

None of these items have changed the number of requests it takes to freeze the server.  I have run the same server locally and it does not stop responding.

Thanks people you make the world go round!

Edit:
Here is example of the logs when it freezes.  I have loaded the default route with does not make calls to the database.

```
2022-11-19 13:35:21 default[20221118t223510]  "POST /admin/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302
2022-11-19 13:35:21 default[20221118t223510]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-19 13:35:22 default[20221118t223510]  "GET /static/css/dist/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-19 13:35:24 default[20221118t223510]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-19 13:35:24 default[20221118t223510]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
```

And then it is just spinning, and the instances seem to be stuck:
[image: Image of the instances]

Comment: Do you have this problem on your local environment? What does the log in the entry for the last time the App correctly loaded a page? Do you have this problem if you're not connected to your SQL DB?

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce this locally, I have appended what I see in the logs above.  I have attempted to remove the DB as a concern by doing the refresh on a page that doesn't hit the DB.

Comment: I may have figured it out, but not sure why it was causing issues.  There must have been some errors that I wasn't seeing based on the `DEBUG = True` being set in the environment.  I have set that to `False` and I am not seeing that behavior.  Going to do some more exploring and try to write up an answer to help others avoid this.

Comment: @TimOverly Have you figured out a solution? if so, can you share the solution?

Comment: @RohitKharche Yea, it was caused by the DEBUG = True. Still don't know why

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out how to stop this.  I had `DEBUG = true` set in my environment file.  If I set that to false it quit restarting.  I think this was due to some health checks that the app environment was doing.  But that is a bit of a guess.